# kombu for RabbitMQ cancel_by_queue method raise ChannelError - PreconditionFailed: Basic.ack

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange, kombu

Using `amqp==2.6.1` with `kombu==4.6.11` - when trying to remove some queue using the  method:

> self.consumer.**cancel_by_queue**(queue_name)

the kombu library does the following:

```
    def cancel_by_queue(self, queue):
        """Cancel consumer by queue name."""
        qname = queue.name if isinstance(queue, Queue) else queue
        try:
            tag = self._active_tags.pop(qname)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            self.channel.basic_cancel(tag)
        finally:
            self._queues.pop(qname, None)
```

and amqp library does the following:

```
    def basic_cancel(self, consumer_tag, nowait=False, argsig='sb'):
        if self.connection is not None:
            self.no_ack_consumers.discard(consumer_tag)
            return self.send_method(
                spec.Basic.Cancel, argsig, (consumer_tag, nowait),
                wait=None if nowait else spec.Basic.CancelOk,
            )
```

which resulting in:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1440, in basic_cancel
wait=None if nowait else spec.Basic.CancelOk,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 68, in send_method
return self.wait(wait, returns_tuple=returns_tuple)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 88, in wait
self.connection.drain_events(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 508, in drain_events
while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 514, in blocking_read
return self.on_inbound_frame(frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 55, in on_frame
callback(channel, method_sig, buf, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 521, in on_inbound_method
method_sig, payload, content,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 145, in dispatch_method
listener(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 280, in _on_close
reply_code, reply_text, (class_id, method_id), ChannelError,
 amqp.exceptions.PreconditionFailed: Basic.ack: (406) PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1234
```

reading the documentation I saw that:

> The client should not wait for a reply method, and If the server could
> not complete the method it will raise a channel or connection
> exception.

and

> The client may receive an abitrary number of messages in between
> sending the cancel method and receiving the cancel-ok reply.

So What is the right way to use **cancel_by_queue** and why this exception has even been raised - and how to prevent it?

Comment: have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567689/rabbitmq-precondition-failed-unknown-delivery-tag

Comment: yes, not helpful...

Comment: it is possible you may have a typo or wrong use somewhere. can you edit your question to include stripped-down codes for "how you define consumer", "how you define/add a queue to consumer", "how you call cancel method".

Comment: I cant provide more code, I call cancel method as shown.
Maybe you could show what is "the right use" of the cancellation method.

Comment: "unknown delivery tag 1234" can be an early/late cancellation, double cancellation, using the wrong channel, using the wrong queue/name or as in quotes you used "waiting for a reply where you shouldn't wait for a reply". you have provided only codes for what is already in those libraries and a simple line where you call which really says nothing about your use of these libraries. it might be a real bug in them, or simply wrong usage on your side but cant say without seeing your way. "stripped down" version also means you narrow down the error and maybe find your own answer trying to do that