# RabbitMQ operation basic.ack caused a channel exception precondition_failed: unknown delivery tag 3 - Golang

Tags: go, error-handling, rabbitmq, consumer, rabbitmqctl

I have two queue in golang which is listen the same time different queue.But some error occured time-by-time in RabbitMQ Side

```
2022-04-13 08:05:54.175 [error] <0.16833.401> Channel error on connection <0.16453.401> (10.32.2.19:47668 -> 10.32.2.5:5672,
    operation basic.ack caused a channel exception precondition_failed: unknown delivery tag 3
```

I have a two different handler function which handles different queues and receive message and ack message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567689/rabbitmq-precondition-failed-unknown-delivery-tag

Comment: @Cyril not the same situation.Why closed ?)

Comment: not me. I don't have permission to close. Just want to show you some hints in that link "
"PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag" usually happens because of double ack-ing, ack-ing on wrong channels or ack-ing messages that should not be ack-ed."